# how to save only ticked checkbox among other checkboxes having same id in cookies

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, checkbox, displaytag

I Am creating an online test application using struts2 framework. am using displaytag in jsp to iterate the list of question and answers. here is the code.

```
 <form method="get">

<display:table name="${sessionScope.questionList}" id="quest" pagesize="1"    

       requestURI="display.jsp">
           <display:column title="Stuff">
            <c:out value="${quest.quesId}"/><br/>
            <c:out value=" ${quest.question}"/><br/>   

    <input type="checkbox" name="ans1" value="${quest.option1}" id="ans1" />  <c:out value="${quest.option1}"/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ans2" value="${quest.option2}" id="ans2"/> <c:out value="${quest.option2}"/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ans3" value="${quest.option3}" id="ans3"/> <c:out value="${quest.option3}"/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ans4" value="${quest.option4}" id="ans4"/> <c:out value="${quest.option4}"/><br/>
        </display:column>
</display:table>
</form>
```

now whenever the user selects a checkbox option it has to be stored in the cookies so that when the user returns to that page the checkbox should not get unchecked. how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This code is off the top of my head and untested. Please read the documentation (or Google it) to get the details right. It is based on jQuery and the [jQuery cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/).

First, read the value of a checkbox when clicked and store it in a cookie:

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("click", function (event) {
  var id = $(this).attr("id"),
    currentlySavedIds = $.cookie('saved_ids');
  currentlySavedIds.push(id);
  $.cookie('saved_ids', currentlySavedIds);
}
```

Then, when the page loads:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var ids = $.cookie('saved_ids');
  $.each(ids, function (index, id) {
    $("#" + id).prop("checked", true);
  }
}
```